# mod_rewrite not working on apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-16.04

I'm banging my head for hours on this: I'm finalizing the setup of my new Ubuntu 16.04 server and everything is going fine now except for the mod_rewrite module on Apache2 which is not working.

In my apache2.conf I added:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
</ifModule>
```

I did the "sudo a2enmod rewrite" command and restarted the service.

For testing I created the following mod_rewrite.php file:

```
<?php echo "Mod_rewrite is activated!"; ?>
```

And the follwing .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ mod_rewrite.php
```

When I access the site all I get is a directory listing of the home folder.

Now I'm out of ideas as to what to do to correct this issue so any help is welcome!

Comment: Turn off indexing `Options -Indexes`, 1 and 2, make sure PHP files are being parsed by apache, and 3 make sure .htaccess use is enabled for your vhost via `AllowOverride` directive.  There's more to it than just enabling mod_rewrite

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1 and 2 are not a problem but I forgot about the AllowOverride directive. Since it's the fifth server I setup in a year I do feel a little stupid right now! Starting from today, it's been added to my standard setup procedure.